# How to collapse contents of a databound ListBoxItem when a button is clicked in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ListBox in my WPF MVVM app using the following code:

```
                            <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,-58">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                           Margin="0,0,0,8" 
                                           FontWeight="Bold" 
                                           Text="{x:Static p:Resources.AvaliableLEDsLabel}" />
                                <ListBox Name="AvailableLEDsListbox" SelectionMode="Extended"
                                         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                                         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                                         dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateListBoxItem}"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLeds}"
                                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                         >
                                    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                                        <StaticResource ResourceKey="StyleListBoxGroup" />
                                    </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                                </ListBox>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </GroupBox>
```

This displays grouped lists of devices, with LEDs under them. The DataTemplate is the following:

```
                                <GroupStyle x:Key="StyleListBoxGroup">
                                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Button Command="{Binding HideGroupCommand}">X</Button>
                                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                                   Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle>

                            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateListBoxItem">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="LedId" Text="{Binding LedId}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
```

I would like to make the X button in the header hooked up to the `HideGroupCommand` toggle the hiding of all the items under that particular header. How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the command defined and how is it implemented...?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options.
First one :
You would need to have a property in your view model something like 'ListBoxVisibility' then u would bind that property to your UI. In command text u just changed visibility property of that property in view model- so u have it reflected on UI. This visibility property can be of type 'bool' , or 'Visibility' or whatever. Only if it's type of Visibility u don't need converter when binding.

NOTE : Some people use it - even though it kinda goes out of general principel of MVVM patter. But sometimes u have to do it.

Second
If wanna stick to MVVM , then u need to fully separate your UI from your viewmodel. Create click event and change visibility.